# Xamarain Android ImageView flashes black when updating quickly

Tags: android, imageview, xamarin

So I have an imageview which I use setImageBitmap(pic) about about 30fps as a form of video stream, and the imageview image (not the rest of the screen) flashes black or disappears every few seconds. Is there a special setting to the imageview I need to add or disable in order to make it not go blank or flicker? I tried setting the imageview image, the layout's background image, VideoView, and all of them flicker black every few seconds while I update the background image. Any fix?

The image is about 320px wide and im not sure how tall, less than 320 tho.

Code doesn't really seem necessary, but this is all im doing ('imageStream' is the ImageView):

```
RunOnUiThread (() => StreamActivity.imageStream.SetImageBitmap(pic));



  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewStream"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="true" />
```

EDIT: I tried setting to software layer type, hardware layer type, and setting background color to Color.Argb(1, 0, 0, 0)
None of that worked.

EDIT: I seem to have fixed it by setting the application to run as hardware accelerated, and also the imageview and layout as hardware accelerated.
Then i changed my image setting code to

```
 Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(pic.Width, pic.Height, Bitmap.Config.Rgb565);
 Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap); // then draw to the Canvas.
 tempCanvas.DrawBitmap(pic, 0, 0, null);
 RunOnUiThread (() => StreamActivity.imageStream.SetImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(tempBitmap)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it by setting the application to run as hardware accelerated, and also the imageview and layout as hardware accelerated.
Then i changed my image setting code to

```
 Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(pic.Width, pic.Height, Bitmap.Config.Rgb565);
 Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap); // then draw to the Canvas.
 tempCanvas.DrawBitmap(pic, 0, 0, null);
 RunOnUiThread (() => StreamActivity.imageStream.SetImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(tempBitmap)));
```

and in my OnCreate()

```
imageStream.SetLayerType(LayerType.Hardware, null);
frameLayout1.SetLayerType(LayerType.Hardware, null);
```

and in my androidmanifest:

```
<application 
 android:label="MyName"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

i thnk its because of RunOnUiThread.

if just want to change image in imageview jst use

ImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thumbs_down);

Comment: I'm settin the image from outside of the activity, so if I don't do RunOnUiThread then nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by creating a BitmapDrawable from the bitmap OFF the UI thread, then calling SetImageDrawable ON the UI thread, then disposing of the BitmapDrawable.

I don't know why this works but I guess there is some overhead taken care of when creating the drawable that lightens the load on the draw routine.

I'm using Xamarin but you get the idea (the eventArgs.Frame is an Android Bitmap):

```
 _stream.NewFrame += (object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) => 
        {
            var bd = new BitmapDrawable(eventArgs.Frame);
            (Context as Activity).RunOnUiThread(() => 
            {
                SetImageDrawable(bd);
                bd.Dispose();
            });
        };
```